# Split a Content by list of strings

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to apply the split words on and email content .It would be helpful let me know if something is missing or any workaround

Have tried below but it is not excepted result

```
List<string> emailSplitterStrings = new List<string>();
            emailSplitterStrings.Add("as");
            emailSplitterStrings.Add(".");
            string content1 = "as Hey Cassie! as u know i am fine.reply soon";            
            List<string> split = content1.Split(emailSplitterStrings.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();
```

Above code gives results : "Hey C","sie!","u know i am fine","reply soon"

Expected result : "Hey Cassie!","u know i am fine","reply soon"

Comment: Why are you surprised you get `"Hey C","sie!"` when your emailSplitterStrings has `as` ?

Comment: We had only a char as a delimiter now added a string as delimiter so looking quick fix

Comment: can you change code line like this, `emailSplitterStrings.Add("as ");`

Comment: @HardikLeuwa yes thanks, Adding spaces before and after "as" would resolve that .But juss want to know if there are some other precise way.

Comment: Regex and word boundaries... why do you want to split on `as` anyway?

Comment: I would suggest to replace "as" by another string, using regex, before you split

Comment: Not as such only string "as" but their are some other strings as well which mean as a end of statement.

Comment: @HassanAlhaj good option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use a regex split, with an alternation pattern consisting of the splitter stings from your original script:

```
List<string> emailSplitterStrings = new List<string>();
emailSplitterStrings.Add("as");
emailSplitterStrings.Add(".");
string content1 = "as Hey Cassie! as u know i am fine.reply soon";
string regex = @"\b(?:" + string.Join("|", emailSplitterStrings.Select(Regex.Escape).ToArray()) + @")\b";
List<string> split = Regex.Split(content1, regex).Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();
split.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

This prints:

```
Hey Cassie!
u know i am fine
reply soon
```

Note that the regex pattern we are actually splitting on here is:

```
\b(?:as|\.)\b
```

We place word boundaries around the alternation, in parentheses, to make sure that `as` only matches the standalone word, and does not match things like the `as` in `Cassie`.

Comment: `List<string> emailSplitterStrings = new List<string>();
            emailSplitterStrings.Add(".");
            emailSplitterStrings.Add("as");
            emailSplitterStrings.Add("?");
            string content1 = "as Hey Cassie! as u know? i am fine.reply soon";
            string regex = @"\b(?:" + string.Join("|", emailSplitterStrings.Select(Regex.Escape).ToArray()) + @")\b";
            List<string> split = Regex.Split(content1, regex).Select(x11 => x11.Trim()).ToList();
            split.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);`

Comment: thanks , But not working when i add "?" in splitter string list and in content

Comment: @BhushanMuttha My code works fine for `?` as a delimiter, [see this demo](https://rextester.com/HUXKF37142).

Comment: actually it is split by "as" not by "?" , I have updated the snippet https://rextester.com/YARE12597

Comment: I have answered your original question.  If you have some other question, then consider opening a new one.

Comment: I think it should be generic solution

Comment: It is a very generic solution.

Comment: ok thanks . If we add "?" string emailSplitterStrings and content then it should have work rit. As content and emailSplitterStrings can be change/add.